# pandas: преобразовать тип 'object'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, анализ-данных

Необходимо рассчитать СРМ, однако в датасете необходимый столбец 'Spend' имеет значение 'object',

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test_data.csv',sep=',')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
metrics_cpm = df.groupby('Buyer', as_index= False).agg({'Spend': 'sum', 'Impressions': 'sum'})metrics_cpm
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
metrics_cpm['Cost Per Mille'] = round(metrics_cpm['Spend']/metrics_cpm['Impressions']*1000, 5)metrics_cpm
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

попробовал поменять тип столбца с помощью команды:

`df['Spend'] = df['Spend'].str.replace(',','.','').astype(np.float64)`

однако ошибка сохраняется, как мне произвести рассчет?

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас не просто object, у вас строковое представление кортежа. Поэтому, как положено, приведите в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных.

Comment: У вас в `Spend` явно **список чисел**. Вы сначала разберитесь, что вы с этим **списком** хотите сделать. Может сложить все эти числа между собой, прежде чем делить на `Impressions` или что, или как? Там размерность чисел очень уж разная, не уверен, что их нужно именно складывать.

Comment: @strawdog изменения внесены

Comment: @CrazyElf изменения внесены

Comment: @Shakhnin Ага, теперь понятно. Я подозреваю, что где-то у вас в этом столбце помимо нормальных чисел закралось что-то не числовое. Надо его как-то найти.

Comment: Вот такое `.replace(',','.','')` у вас поменяет вообще всё на пустую строку, вы не проверяли совсем, что на выходе?? У вас вместо этой колонки сплошные `NA` должны получиться при таком `replace`.

Comment: По-моему у вас нормально всё с разделителем разрядов, да и не может быть у вас там нигде `,` внутри колонки, поскольку это у вас разделитель колонок. Попробуйте сделать просто `df['Spend'] = df['Spend'].astype(np.float64)` и посмотрите, какая ошибка выскочит. Так вы наверняка увидите в ошибке, какое значение не даёт колонке стать числовой колонкой.

Comment: @CrazyElf could not convert string to float: '3208,440002' вот такая...

Comment: @Shakhnin Хм. Ну если только у вас ещё и в кавычках содержимое колонок, тогда может быть такой же разделитель дробной части, как и разделитель колонок... А попробуйте параметр `decimal=','` добавить в `pd.read_csv`, так более правильно, чем делать `replace`. Ну или если хотите всё же replace, то такой: `.replace(',','.')`, без добавки в конце, которая всё в пустую строку превращает.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо! получилось!

Comment: Хорошо, оформлю как ответ тогда )

Comment: @CrazyElf уделите ещё минуту пожалуйста... есть выручка за 1ый день за 7ой и 30ый, как можно эти столбцы объединить и разделить их на /metrics_cr['Impressions']*100, 5)

Comment: Да просто сложите их через + или что вы хотите? Pandas может складывать, делить и т.д. Скобки только не забывайте, если нужно сложить, а потом разделить

Comment: @CrazyElf с сложением понятно, я сложил данные из трех столбцов выручки, получил результат на каждый столбец, с помощью какого кода эту выручку за 1, 7, 30 можно суммировать в один столбик, чтобы произвести деление

Comment: @Shakhnin Без иллюстраций непонятно. Так то просто пишете `(metrics_cpm['Выручка1']+metrics_cpm['Выручка7']+metrics_cpm['Выручка30'])/metrics_cpm['Impressions']` и всё, но возможно я не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать. Лучше задайте новый, отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте параметр `decimal=','` в вызов `pd.read_csv`, это более правильно, чем делать `replace` вручную потом. Конечно, это странноватая ситуация, когда у вас и разделитель колонок и разделитель разрядов один и тот же символ `,`, но в принципе такое может быть, в этом случае содержимое колонок приходит в кавычках и `Pandas` может разобраться где что.

Либо, если хочется всё же менять вручную, можно делать `.str.replace(',','.')`, а ваш вариант `.str.replace(',','.','')` заменял всё в на пустую строку, которая превращалась в итоге в значения `NA` после преобразования в `float`.